# awk: split column, print left side of delimiter and paste in the middle of csv

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, cut, csv-simple

Input file:

```
AAA, BBB:XXX, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH
```

Output should be:

```
AAA, BBB, BBB:XXX, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH
```

I thought about something like:

```
awk -F, '{n=split($2,a,":"); a[n]} {$2=$NF","$2}1' OFS=,
```

But the first "split" uses the right side of the delimiter instead of the left and the copy at the end copies the HHH instead of the BBB.

Comment: Wait. your expected output and the last line in your question is contrast... can you cross check.

Comment: Do we need XXX or BBB in second field ?

Comment: Output should look like: AAA, BBB, BBB:XXX, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH, second field splitted on the left side of the : and inserted on $2 leaving the initial $2 as $3

Comment: I have edited your question. plz crosscheck.

Answer (score 2):

With single `awk`:

```
awk -F'[:,]' '{$3=$2":"$3}1' OFS=, infile
AAA, BBB, BBB:XXX, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if (split($i, a, ":") > 1) $i = a[1] OFS $i } 1' file
AAA, BBB, BBB:XXX, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH
```

You will have to iterate through all fields, and when you find a field that splits into more than one string when you split on `:`, then you need to prepend the first part of that split string to the value of that field.

If you know it's always going to be the second field:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '{ split($2, a, ":"); $2 = a[1] OFS $2 } 1' file
AAA, BBB, BBB:XXX, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH
```

In your code, `n` will be the number of strings that the data was split into, so `a[n]` will be the last (rightmost) `:`-delimited string in `$2`.

---

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/\([^,: ]*\):/\1, &/g' file
AAA, BBB, BBB:XXX, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH
```

This would replace any string not containing `,`, `:` or space, and that are followed immediately by a `:` with itself twice (the second time with the final `:` included).

Remove the `g` at the end of the `s` command if you only ever expect to make a single replacement (as in your example).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk -F, '{n=split($2,a,":"); a[n]} {$2=a[1]","$2}1' OFS=, file
AAA, BBB, BBB:XXX, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH
```

Your assigning last field and a second field to $2 (`$2=$NF","$2`) instead of assigning fist split in `a` with the second field (`$2=a[1]","$2`)

Answer (score 0):

A simple non-awk approach

```
$ ( cut -f1 -d: file ; cut -f2- -d, file ) | paste -sd,
AAA, BBB, BBB:XXX, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH
$
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick `sed` option

```
sed -r 's/, \w+/&&/'
```

The `\w+` expression matches alphanumerics (in your example the `BBB`) but not punctuation or whitespace. The `&` represents the entire match.

Example

```
echo 'AAA, BBB:XXX, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH' | sed -r 's/, \w+/&&/'
AAA, BBB, BBB:XXX, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH
```